# How to get command run with subprocess Popen

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a way to get back the command line to be executed with a Popen?

```
command = Popen(['ls', '-l'])
```

How can I get `ls -l` from the command object? I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For python-2.7 the arguments are not stored as in from version 3.3. What you have to do is either to remember them or make a workaround.

One way would be to write your own inheriting from `Popen` or simply writing a wrapper around `Popen`:

```
from subprocess import _Popen

def Popen(*args, **kwds):
    res = _Popen(*args, **kwds)

    if not hasattr(res, "args"):
        res.args = args[0]

    return res
```

of course you could store all the positional and keyword arguments if you want to. Before 3.3 the `args` attribute is not being used, but afterwards it is so you might want to protect from that as shown above.

You could even do the check once (at startup) and use some monkey patching. Here's an example with inheritance:

```
from sys import version
import subprocess

class Popen(subprocess.Popen):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        subprocess.Popen.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.args = args[0]

if version[0] < 3 or (version[0]==3 and version[1] < 3): # pre 3.3
    subprocess.Popen = Popen
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Python 3, `command.args` is the easiest way:

```
from subprocess import Popen
command = Popen(['ls', '-l'])

print command.args
```

Output:

```
['ls', '-l']
```

Note that the output is a list.

Comment: Oh! I get the following: AttributeError: 'Popen' object has no attribute 'args' which version of python are you using?

Comment: @Har Oops, I'm using Python 3.5. Sorry about that, I'll edit my answer ;)

Comment: @Har Well, I've just leave. Seems like skyking has post the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is still informative as I don't usually use python 3, its helpful to know that this is already present in future versions of python.

Comment: @Har And I've just add the tip. I'm happy that you found the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes do it this way!

```
import subprocess,
cmd = ["ls", "-a" ]
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
stdout = proc.communicate()[0]
```